# Ethereum cross-chain/cross DLT

Tags: cross-chain

What functionalities/standards does Ethereum have that can be used in cross-chain or cross-DLT operations?
What is the recommended solution when someone need to do an atomic swap? And other cross operations?

Comment: There are no functionalities/standards in terms of this topic. Check out https://cosmos.network/